# AngularJS non-ascii property name support

Tags: angularjs, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I don't know how to use non-ascii property name in AngularJS. I could print a value by using `a['property_name']` instead of `a.property_name`, but I couldn't use the same way in 'orderBy'. If I click on 'name', sorting would happen, but if I click on '가격_price', nothing would happen and an error would show up in the console. How could I sort a table which has non-ascii name?

(There are Korean Characters in the code, but I think it makes sense.)

http://jsfiddle.net/k9h32mh9/

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><a ng-click="predicate='name'; reverse=false">name</a></th>
                <th><a ng-click="predicate='가격_price'; reverse=false">가격(price)</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item['가격_price']}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.predicate = '-name';
    $scope.items = [{name: "a", 가격_price:"1000"},
                    {name: "b", 가격_price:"2000"},
                    {name: "c", 가격_price:"1500"}];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need your attribute names in a mixed English-Korean? Just as a human being I can tell you: it looks so ugly... And why do you believe you must have these symbols in your properties names at all? My native language is far away from English but I never had any problem with English names for everything

Comment: The object wasn't made by me, so I would have to manually change the property names unless I find a solution to this problem, and I'm mixing English with Korean because I'm worried about people who may not have Korean fonts.

Comment: Not currently possible (on-going discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2174 ). For now, it sounds like your only option is to preprocess the data when you retrieve it, so that your keys are in the Angular-accepted characters. (Unless, of course, you want to build your own versions of the built in directives -- I do not suggest that route, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is an issue with Angular, as per https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2174, it can be worked around by specifying your own predicate function on the scope in order to access the property to sort by:

```
$scope.predicateProperty = 'name';
$scope.predicate = function(a) {
    return a[$scope.predicateProperty];
};
```

And the HTML can be almost identical, just setting `predicateProperty` to the property name that you want to sort by (I've also removed references to "reverse" as it slightly complicates the issue)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><a ng-click="predicateProperty='name';">name</a></th>
        <th><a ng-click="predicateProperty='가격_price';">가격(price)</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:predicate">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item['가격_price']}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see this working at http://jsfiddle.net/k9h32mh9/5/